# I want to update last date in to multiple same id

Tags: sql-server

The present record is like this

[image: given table]

I want output to be like this

[image: output image]

I need a SQL query for this concept

Thanks

Comment: What criteria are you applying to choose the date and which rows will it be copied to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following construct:

```
SELECT name, email, completedClaims, canceledClaims, 
       MAX(datecolumn) OVER (PARTITION BY idcolumn) AS lastDate
FROM Table ;
```

I'm not sure what your columns and tables are called or what your id is (`name`? `email`?) so I called it `idcolumn`.

Comment: Actually i brought that four columns by joining with 5 tables thatswhy i didn't mentioned id